# Error when send data with rabbit MQ MessageConversionException: failed to convert to serialized Message content

Tags: java, json, rabbitmq

Follow my code

1. Read data from DB

> DataUnsend unsend = new DataUnsend();
> unsend.setAttachments(resultSet.getClob("json_attachments"));

json_attachments with sample json

> [
> {
> "name": "1.txt",
> "content_type": "text/plain",
> "content": "",
> "content_id": "",
> "is_inline": false
> },
> {
> "name": "2.txt",
> "content_type": "text/plain",
> "content": "",
> "content_id": "",
> "is_inline": false
> }
> ]

2. Send data used rabbitMQ

> @Autowired
> private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

```
ArrayList<DataUnsend> dataArray = jobs.getDataUnsendEmail();
            System.out.println("size DataUnsendEmail: " + dataArray.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.size(); i++) {
                DataUnsend data = dataArray.get(i);
                rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(emailQueueName, data);
            }
```

But I have error **org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to convert to serialized Message content**

Show how can i fix it?

Comment: can you https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?